# Find gaps between date ranges for users in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need to know how much time (days) users were logged and the gaps between non-logged time. In this table I just store the id and their start and end date (ID, INI, FIN, respectively). I've already managed to detect gaps on three records based on conditionals by grouping users with row number and then compare newest log against the following and so on.

The problem is that I have people with n logs historically and I can't write n left joins and n conditionals. I'm looking to make my current code more scalable detecting these gaps more recursively and more user "understandable".

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[baseRecurrentes](
    [ID] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [INI] [datetime] NULL,
    [FIN] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA1', CAST(0x0000A9C800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9E600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA1', CAST(0x0000A9E700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA0200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA1', CAST(0x0000AA0300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA2100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA1', CAST(0x0000AA2200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA3F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA2', CAST(0x0000A9D600000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9D900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA2', CAST(0x0000A9EB00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9ED00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA2', CAST(0x0000A9F000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9F100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA3', CAST(0x0000AA1A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA5A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA4', CAST(0x0000A9CA00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9CB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A8DC00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A8F100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A8F200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A90F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A91000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A92E00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A92F00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A94D00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A94E00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A96B00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A96C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A98A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A98B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9A800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A9A900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9C700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A9C800000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A87900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000A9E700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA0200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000AA0300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA2100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000AA2200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA3F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA5', CAST(0x0000AA4000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA5000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA6', CAST(0x0000AA0900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA2900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA7', CAST(0x0000A96C00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A98A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA7', CAST(0x0000A98B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9A800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA7', CAST(0x0000A9A900000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A9C700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA7', CAST(0x0000A85B00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A87900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA7', CAST(0x0000A9E700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA0200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[baseRecurrentes] ([ID], [INI], [FIN]) VALUES (N'PERSONA7', CAST(0x0000AA0300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000AA2100000000 AS DateTime))

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY INI DESC)
    FROM BASERECURRENTES
), CTE2 AS (
    --
    SELECT DISTINCT T.ID,
    -- 
    CAST(T2.INI AS DATETIME) AS INI1, CAST(T2.FIN AS DATETIME) AS FIN1, 
    -- 
    CAST(T3.INI AS DATETIME) AS INI2, CAST(T3.FIN AS DATETIME) AS FIN2, 
    --
    CAST(T4.INI AS DATETIME) AS INI3, CAST(T4.FIN AS DATETIME) AS FIN3 
    --
    FROM CTE T
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID AND T2.RN = 1 
    LEFT JOIN CTE T3 ON T.ID = T3.ID AND T3.RN = 2
    LEFT JOIN CTE T4 ON T.ID = T4.ID AND T4.RN = 3

), CTE3 AS (
    SELECT *, MSG = (CASE 
                                --NO GAPS ON 3 LOGS
                                WHEN (INI1 - 1 BETWEEN INI2 AND FIN2) AND (INI2 - 1 BETWEEN INI3 AND FIN3) THEN 'SEC2' 
                                --NO GAPS ON 2 LOGS
                                WHEN (INI1 - 1 BETWEEN INI2 AND FIN2) THEN 'SEC1' 
                                --NO GAP AT ALL
                                ELSE 'NO SEC'
                            END)

    FROM CTE2
)
SELECT * FROM CTE3
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

I expect a table showing the user ID, "gap days" (sum of non logged time) and a message showing where the gaps are.

```
ID       GD  MSG
-------------------
PERSONA2 5   GAP ON X-Y
```

Comment: So, for the data you have, what is the expected results? This sounds like you're after a calendar or tally table.

Comment: @Larnu, something that shows users with gaps on their records and if possible, where the gap is. I have a calendar table but pairing it with my current table isn't making it more easy to work on. I'm kinda clueless on this requirement.

Comment: @AbdónAraya . . . Nothing in your data model identifies a "user".  Sample data and desired results in a *text table* format would help.  And why are you representing dates using hex formats?  That makes the question much harder to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ID corresponds to the user and dates somehow were generated as hex by ms script generator

Comment: Sounds like a classic "Gaps in time series" problem. See if this helps: http://tomaslind.net/2015/07/07/how-to-fill-in-gaps-in-time-series/, Also Joe Celko's "Time series" writings are excellent at this sort of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you the "recursive" results you're looking for, by comparing each user's span to the user's previous span. This sums up all results to the user; selecting from CTE2 can return the spans with gaps or where Ini/Fin are reversed.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
        Person_RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY INI, FIN),
        Person_Count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM BASERECURRENTES
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT T.*,
        N_Days_Logged_On = 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T.Ini, T.Fin) < 0 THEN NULL -- Reversed span
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, T.Ini, T.Fin) 
        END,
        N_Days_Gap_From_Prev = 
        CASE
            WHEN T.Person_RN = 1 THEN NULL -- First span
            WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, tPrev.Fin) = t.Ini THEN 0 -- OP allowed a one-day gap
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, tPrev.Fin, T.Ini) 
        END,
        tPrev.Ini AS Ini_Prev, tPrev.Fin AS Fin_Prev
    FROM CTE T
    LEFT JOIN CTE TPrev ON T.ID = TPrev.ID AND TPrev.Person_RN = (T.Person_RN - 1)
    -- LEFT JOIN CTE TNext ON T.ID = TNext.ID AND TNext.Person_RN = (T.Person_RN + 1) 
), CTE3 AS (
    SELECT ID,
        GD = SUM(N_Days_Gap_From_Prev),
        N_Days_Logged_On = SUM(N_Days_Logged_On),
        N_Logs = MAX(Person_Count),
        N_Spans_WO_Gaps = COUNT(CASE WHEN N_Days_Gap_From_Prev = 0 THEN ID ELSE NULL END),
        N_Spans_W_Gaps = COUNT(NULLIF(N_Days_Gap_From_Prev, 0)),
        -- Captures reversed/invalid(?) spans, plus incomplete spans (null Ini or Fin)
        N_Spans_Suspect = COUNT(CASE WHEN N_Days_Logged_On IS NULL THEN ID ELSE NULL END)
    FROM CTE2
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE3
ORDER BY ID
```

I made a couple of assumptions with this. From your example, it looks like logon/logoff are dates stored as datetime, but the time portion isn't a concern (e.g., logoff at 00:00 is the same as 23:59). And as you can see in CTE2, DATEDIFF results aren't necessarily intuitive (e.g., DATEDIFF for 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-31 is 30 days).

From the sample data, this returns:

- PERSONA1: 4 logs, 0 gap days, 116 days logged on, and 0 spans with gaps
- PERSONA2: 3 logs, 21 gap days, 6 days logged on, and all spans have gaps.

Comment: It's almost exactly what I asked, but with your code I managed to accomplish the requirement! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `ROW_NUMBER()`s in joining to the same `CTE` and look for the gaps.  Here's what I suggest:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY INI DESC)
    FROM BASERECURRENTES
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT * 
         , (SELECT TOP 1 FIN FROM CTE b WHERE a.ID = b.ID and b.RN > a.RN) ENDOFLAST
    FROM CTE a
), CTE3 AS (
    SELECT *
         , DATEDIFF(DAY, INI, ENDOFLAST) GAPDAYS
    FROM CTE2
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE3
WHERE GAPDAYS < -1
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

and a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0515/11).  I didn't exactly understand the actual message, but I think the result set has everything you need to create the message.